# Playing Two AVPlayers with two remote videos in sync [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

As titled, I'm currently working on an app that needs to play two videos on a server. The thing is I need to play these two videos in sync which means two of the AVPlayers start the video exactly at the same time, and whenever one of the AVPlayer is paused due to buffering, the other AVPlayer needs to be paused, along with the resumed after buffer and vice versa.

I tried to look around but can't really seem to find a solution to this case.

I need to play it via stream which means my business requirement won't allow me to download both of the videos first.

Comment: Please have a look on it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544239/stream-2-videos-simultaneously-swift

Comment: Did you find solution ?